# What's the maximum number of rows for a FlatFileSource (SSIS dataflow object)

Tags: ssis

I'm having an issue, or maybe just lack of knowledge from my behalf, regarding SSIS.
  I'm trying to import a huge csv file, via SSIS (flat file source and ado.net destination) to a MS Sql Server (2012) table.
  The dataflow object works perfectly for a small file, which has only 600 rows from the initial one (about 19 million records), but when I try to import the latest (the one having 19 million records), it (the dataflow task) does not fail but it only process one record, not just a few, not several, only one record (i did not check what record was it, the first, or just a random one)...is there any restriction for the flat file source, in SSIS?
   If that is the case, is there any information regarding what is that limit? Because, how should I proceed, to try splitting the huge file into several smaller ones?
   In my case I must use flat file when transferring the data to MS Sql Server, so any hints?

Many thanks,

Comment: You likely have bad data in that file. In 2010, we were ripping apart 50GB files just fine. Bad data takes many forms: embedded column or row delimiter, a carriage return or linefeed, incorrect number of columns, etc

Comment: @billinkc: Thanks for your hint. Apparently, each of 22 million records, had a lot of spaces. After successfully trimmed the file, from ~9GB it has now ~1GB and it (SSIS) processes all rows, not just the first one. Thanks again.